# RAM ejector clips stuck after replacing RAM on late 2006 20" iMac Core 2 Duo

Tags: imac, memory

We have a 9-year-old iMac, and it's still running fine except that it started to slow down. So we decided to upgrade the RAM to 3 GB. Following the instructions on Apple's support site for replacing RAM, we opened the ejector clips, removed the old RAM, put in the new RAM, pushed it in with thumbs, not the clips, till it clicked in to place (though possible I pushed one slightly too hard/far? It looks about the same as the other one in terms of how deep it is though, and they are too hard to remove without the clips which are already open), and tried to close the ejector clips after them to lock it in place. However, the ejector clips don't want to go in. I know they had a little resistance when originally opening them, but I'm concerned that if I try too hard to close it again that they will break or damage something. Is this a possibility?

Further, we simply put the iMac back upright and plugged it in, and it actually is working and reading all 3 GB of RAM (and running more smoothly than before). Does that indicate that we did something wrong or right?

Should we leave well enough alone, try to force the clips shut, or what?

Comment: I don't know that particular machine, but the general idea with RAM clips is they self-return as you push the RAM home. So, without being able to see it, my only guess would be, it's not home yet. Looking at the pictures on https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201191 would reinforce my belief, as that looks like a pretty standard fitting for its time. Having said that… don't force it, make sure your path is clear & the RAM correctly oriented.

Comment: @Tetsujin Interesting. But both sticks are being read, so how could they not be fully in? Again, they felt as though they settled in place. Also, I'm wondering, since it started with two 1-GB sticks, and I had to open the clips to remove one of them, but that released both sticks, then when I put the 2-GB stick in, I had to push both back in to place, one at a time. Could that have affected the clips? Must they both be pushed in simultaneously?

Comment: I don't know the model well-enough to really be able to advise. You do get a feel for what RAM feels like as it goes fully home, but even with practise you can still get one slightly out of square & always should double-check by eye. Standard RAM clips will not close until the RAM is home, as a precaution against partial insertion. Those Apple clips are non-standard, though, so it's hard for me to be precise in this particular case.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. But I mean, I pushed them in quite firmly, they felt like they went all the way in, the computer actually is working and reading both RAM sticks, could that happen if it wasn't all the way in? Do you know if the clips are *supposed* to feel like they might snap and break when returning them, and are they sturdy to prevent actual damage?

Comment: I really don't know, sorry - I was hoping someone with better experience of that particular model might have chimed in by now...